# Study App have a huge number of activities

Tags: android

I am started to craete a learning app for 8,9,10,11 and 12 classes. I am created Activities for each classes... and in every classes have subjects and chapters. I created each of that Activity. At last there is a huge number of activity classes are made...

My questian is there is any way to create this app without creating this huge number if activities?

Is there is a simple and powerfull way there?

please reply anyone please with advance thanks....

Comment: is ur UI same and only difference is subjects and chapters? From where are you getting subjects and chapters? database ? api?

Please provide more info if possible to give a good answer , thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with a single `Activity` or `Fragment`. Let me explain. In `MainActivity` you should show all the class options (8,9,10,11,12). When a user clicks on a particular class then you can invoke another `Activity` or `Fragment` which shows data for that particular class. Let us suppose the name of that activity is `LearnActivity`. So whenever a user clicks on a particular class in `MainActivity` you should send data with intent to `LearnActivity`. For example if user clicks on class 8, you send 8 as extra in a `Bundle` with intent to `LearnActivity`. Based on this value you can show subjects and chapters for that particular class. Thus you need not to create a lot of activities.